# getResponseHeaders is not working, I can't see what it's returning

Tags: google-chrome-extension

First off, here is the code of my chrome extension:

```
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", link, true);
        xhr.send();
        xhr.send();

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState == this.HEADERS_RECEIVED) {
            var contentLenght = xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Lenght")
            console.log(contentLenght )
            if(contentLenght=="0") {
                doThing()
            }
            }
        };
```

doThing() isn't called even if contentLenght is 0, nothing is written in the console, and I can't see any value for contentLenght when I press F12. Additionally, the debugging is really weird and often the page just stops working and all buttons to continue to the next breakpoint dissapear, or the page just waits for the next point forever. It looks like something is really wrong with this, but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

The omly problem was that I was typing lenght instead of length!